# Build log4cxx [DEBIAN]

Tags: debian, c++, api

Where to start when building log4cxx package, do I need some other packages for bulding this?

I tried with [this](http://www.radmangames.com/programming/how-to-build-log4cxx-from-source) tutorial but unsuccessful.

If it's possible I would like someone to explain to me whole process of building, installing this log4cxx package. .

Comment: Why do you want to built the package by hand? There is already a pre-built [Log4cxx package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/liblog4cxx10) for Debian. The build-dependencies are listed in [`debian/control` of the corresponding source package](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/log4cxx.git/tree/debian/control).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that the default version of the package does not fulfil your needs and that you need to either tweak the source or configuration.

Try following these steps:

Get all of the dependencies required to build log4cxx

`sudo apt-get build-deps log4cxx`

Download the source for the log4cxx package

`apt-get source log4cxx`

Change directory to source directory

`cd log4cxx-0.10.0`

*Note you may need to tweak this for the version number that came with your system*

You should make any changes you require at this point. Note that if you take a copy of the source directory at this point it will be easy to create a patch with your changes later.

If you want to change configure options look in debian/rules for "./configure", this is where configure is called when the debian package is built, add anything you require here. For example, try changing the line to:

`./configure --prefix=/usr --with-SMTP`

This will build the package with SMTP support.

The final step is to rebuild the package:

`dpkg-buildpackage -b`

The result will be a newly created debian configured for your purposes.

You can install the debian with

`sudo dpkg -i ../liblog4cxx10_0.10.0-1.2ubuntu2_amd64.deb`

*Note that your file name may be slightly different here depending on your system architecture and the version of log4cxx you retrieved from the repositories.*

I would recommend you also change the packages version number and maintainer in debian/control so that you can differentiate between your package and the default one. Beware that if another package depends on a specific version of log4cxx then your package will no longer satisfy the dependency.

I recommend [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28372/how-do-i-get-and-modify-the-source-code-of-packages-installed-through-apt-get) question for further information.